# ERB Radio Button causing string error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

I'm working with forms using `Embedded Ruby` and `Rails 4` to create and edit Users. Each User has to be assigned a Role on creation. Initially the form was using check boxes for this and was working fine. Upon changing over to radio buttons however, I get an error.

This is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :name, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :phone_number %>

  <%= f.input :institution_pid, collection: institutions_for_select, as: :select, label: "Institution" %>

  <%= f.association :roles, collection: roles_for_select, as: :radio_buttons %>

  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>

</div>
<br>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-success") do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Submit
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to @user, {class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-cancel"} do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancel
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm specifically asking about the `f.association` bit. Before, when I was using

```
as: :check_boxes
```

it worked exactly as it was supposed to. Now I get this error message:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#update

undefined method `reject' for "77":String
```

I should note that "77" is the value of one of the radio button options.

The method throwing the error is this:

```
def build_role_ids
  [].tap do |role_ids|
    roles = Role.find(params[:user][:role_ids].reject &:blank?)
    roles.each do |role|
      authorize!(:add_user, role)
      role_ids << role.id
    end
  end
end
```

The HTML when using radio buttons looks like this:

```
<label class="radio">
  <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="user_role_ids_77" name="user[role_ids]" type="radio" value="77">
  "Institutional Admin"
</label>
```

When using check boxes:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input class="check_boxes optional" id="user_role_ids_77" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="77">
  "Institutional Admin"
</label>
```

If I'm missing something or you need more information, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With checkboxes, user can select multiple values so you got an `Array` of role_ids returned in `params[:user][:role_ids]`. `reject` method is implemented for Arrays. Hence, it worked in that case.

With radio buttons, only one value would be selected at a time, so you'll get a `String` value for `role_ids` in `params[:user][:role_ids]`. `reject` method is not implemented for Strings. Hence, the error.

Instead of

```
params[:user][:role_ids].reject &:blank?
```

you can check if `role_ids` is empty or not, as it is a String object.

```
params[:user][:role_ids].empty?
```

and update `build_role_ids` method keeping in mind that `role_ids` is a String object and not an Array.

Comment: I had to do a little more editing of the method than just that line to change from an array to a string but the general idea worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to indicate that `params[:user][:role_ids]` is not an `Array` but a single `String` value. This would make sense since you are changing from checkboxes (multiple values can be selected at a time = Array) to radio buttons (only a single value can be selected at a time = String).

If you truly want to change from checkboxes to radio buttons, then you'll need to update your `build_role_ids` method logic to expect a single value instead of an array of values.